# Is running this in a parallel fashion any faster for downloading remote media files?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to download a list of files, the files are 732 images (size 1280) & 30 videos. For simplicity sake lets just focus on the time it takes to download the 732 images. It will take well over a minute to download 732 images, even running in parallel with a degree of 40+

Here are some benchmarks of how long it took when running each degree of parallelism. Running at a degree of 1, which I expect is just like running non-parallel is taking around 286s which is just over 5 minutes, if I'm running in parallel of atleast 5, shouldn't it be taking no more than a minute?

```
001: 286s
004: 154s
080: 126s
040: 111s
030: 118s
012: 160s
```

Am I being OTT and thinking I can run this much faster when I can't or is this relatively slow? Downloading files are IO bound, but I do have 2 CPU cores.

```
public static void DownloadLinks(Dictionary<string, string> files)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
        files,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 12 },
        currentFile => { DownloadFile(currentFile); }
    );
}

private static void DownloadFile(KeyValuePair<string, string> link, bool retry = false)
{
    try
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
            webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(link.Key), link.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (retry)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            throw;
        }

        if (e.Message.Contains("(504) Gateway Timeout") || e.Message.Contains("(403) Forbidden"))
        {
            if (!RetryFailedDownload(link))
            {
                Logger.Error("Failed to download: " + link.Key);
                Program.FailedDownloads.Add(link.Key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Error("Failed to download: " + link.Key);
            Logger.Error(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

private static bool RetryFailedDownload(KeyValuePair<string, string> link)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        DownloadFile(link, true);

        if (File.Exists(link.Value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that your "slowness" is more processor bound than network bound? You can only make so many outgoing TCP connections... Increasing the parallelism won't help if you only have 2 CPU cores, so spinning off 40 threads on 2 cores may actually slow things down.

Comment: Most likely you were using your full bandwidth with the serial downloading now with parallel it's cutting that bandwidth in half( assuming two threads)

Comment: You're probably limited by how much traffic the network can handle. Parallelizing this will only speed up the processing of the data you've already downloaded.

Comment: I felt bad when I saw this post... it's the first thing I tried on parallel as well.  As Ron said, it's a network/cpu issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you download files form your local network or from the internet your bottleneck is your network or internet connection... So going parallel here is not helping much...

Answer (score 0):

> *Running in parallel isn't much faster for downloading media?*

### Well, no one can tell, unless rigorous saturation test were done ...

Given the few pieces of information, your sketched process consists at least of this pure-**`[SERIAL]`** sequence of components, that "**together**" form a chain-of-actions, that facilitates an illusion of an **End-to-End Service** yet work in a fashion of a pure-`[SERIAL]` abstract flow of ( segmented ) minitasks :

```
----------------------------------<_a-knowingly-over-simplified-E2E-scheme_>
```

1 ) a local pool of application thread(s)
2 ) a local pool of CPU/cores
3 ) a local O/S { scheduler | kernel }-composition
4 ) a local security-ENDEC process
5 ) a local PMD-network pool of access device(s)
6 ) a local segment of L3+network
7 ) a local segment of L3+network composition of { Gateway | Proxy | Firewall }-nodes ( if any )
8 ) an interconnect network with many, non-deterministically harnessed mediating nodes
9 ) a remote segment of L3+network composition of { Gateway | Proxy | Firewall }-nodes ( if any )
10 ) a remote segment of L3+network
11 ) a remote PMD-network pool of access device(s)
12 ) a remote security-ENDEC process
13 ) a remote O/S { scheduler | kernel }-composition
14 ) a remote file-serving application(s)
15 ) a remote filesystem-serving resources
16 ) a remote pool of file-storing device(s)

```
----------------------------------<_a-knowingly-over-simplified-E2E-scheme_>
```

Given the O/P problem definition,
**no one can state,**
**whether** the saturation first appeared in the suffocated **[ 1 ]** thread-pool scaling / **[ 2 ]** CPU/cores scheduler bottleneck, **or** if these components work as hell, yet they remain waiting due to whichever of the (network)-components buffer-saturation, bandwidth-profiling, TypeOfService-policy enforcement or whatever other data-flow issue, **or** ... **or** last, but not least, the item **[ 16 ]** -- due to a principal unability of the remote filesystem-serving Hard Drive-to-controller internal ( unmaskable ) internally-still-SATA hardware interconnect bottleneck...

Given you tested ( as posted above ) CPU-related saturation hypothesis, receiving a data for rejection of such a null-hypothesis, any other of the above listed processing-elements in the chain remain for investigation ( so as to isolate ( best find ) the root cause suspect ).

---

### **Epilogue : A Methodical Remark 
<sub>( not to mix [a true-`[PARALLEL]` with a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) )</sub>  :**

The problem is, by definition, out of question **not** a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** process schedule, but a "just"-`[CONCURENT]` scheduling problem, where resources down the path could be freely used in a "best-effort" manner ( well, actually some policy limited "best-effort", if going yet a bit deeper under the hood ), but obviously **not** orchestrated so as to serve a true-`[PARALLEL]` execution End-to-End, so **concurrent operations** are applicable, not a need to solve the paradigms for solving the End-to-End true-`[PARALLEL]` processing.